# Fatal python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Due to following error python stops running

[image]

In my windows 7 OS i have installed python 2.7 32 bit. This version of python (i.e 2.7) is working fine. Now i have installed python 3.6 version on the same machine. But this version  is now working after installation. When ever i try to open it giving the fatal error. 
Advance thanks for the solution

Comment: This error typically means that python is looking in the wrong place for libraries.  It may help to remove any environment variables, such as PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME, set to point to the 2.7 installation path.